# How to show comma separated values in mvc list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `Students` and a `Skills` table, a student can have multiple skills, so I have a `StudentSkills` that have many to many relationship with `Students` and `Skills`.

I can insert successfully into my table, but I am unable to show my all skills in a single row in my listview. I have tried in different ways like `StringBuilder` or string join but I failed. I don't know what is the code to do that.

Linq doesn't support `StringBuilder` or string join.

This code I have provided results well except that, For each skills, different rows are being generated in List where other items are being repeated in each row.

Here is my code:

Students controller:

```
public ActionResult GetStudentsInfo ()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    var students = (from stud in db.Students
                    join con in db.Countries on stud.CountryId equals con.CountryId
                    join ct in db.Cities on stud.CityId equals ct.CityId
                    join rsm in db.Resumes on stud.ResumeID equals rsm.ResumeId
                    join stsk in db.StudentSkills on stud.StudentId equals stsk.StudentId

                    //group stsk by stsk.StudentId into g
                    //group stud by stud.StudentId into sg

                    select new
                    {
                        studentName = stud.StudentName,
                        countries = con.CountryName,
                        cities = ct.CityName,
                        skills = stsk.Skill.SkillName.ToString(),
                        resumes = rsm.ResumeName,
                        dateOfBirth = stud.DateOfBirth,
                    }).ToList();

    List<StudentListVM> studentLists = new List<StudentListVM>();

    foreach (var item in students)
    {
        //var sk= sb.Append(item.skills + ",").ToString();
        studentLists.Add(new StudentListVM
        {
            studentName = item.studentName,
            countries = item.countries,
            cities = item.cities,
            skills = string.Join(",", item.skills).ToString(),
            //skills = item.skills.ToString(),
            resumes = item.resumes,
            dateOfBirth = item.dateOfBirth
        });
        //sb.Remove(sb.ToString().LastIndexOf(","), 1);
    }

    return View(studentLists);
}
```

Students class:

```
public partial class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.Resumes = new HashSet<Resume>();
        this.StudentSkills = new HashSet<StudentSkill>();
    }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ResumeID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentSkill> StudentSkills { get; set; }
}
```

Skills class:

```
public partial class Skill
{
    public Skill()
    {
        this.StudentSkills = new HashSet<StudentSkill>();
    }

    public int SkillId { get; set; }
    public string SkillName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentSkill> StudentSkills { get; set; }
}
```

StudentsSkills class:

```
public partial class StudentSkill
{
    public int StudentSkillsId { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public int SkillId { get; set; }

    public virtual Skill Skill { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

StudentListVM viewmodel class:

```
public class StudentListVM
{
    public string studentName { get; set; }
    public string countries { get; set; }
    public string cities { get; set; }
    public string skills { get; set; }
    public string resumes { get; set; }
    public DateTime dateOfBirth { get; set; }
}
```

Student List View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCOneSoft.ViewModels.StudentListVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "CreateFromVM")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Student Name
        </th>
        <th>
            City
        </th>
        <th>
            Country
        </th>
        <th>
            Skills
        </th>
        <th>
            Resume
        </th>
        <th>
            Date Of Birth
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.studentName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cities)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.countries)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.skills)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.resumes)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem =>item.dateOfBirth)
        </td>

        //this section is commented

        @*<td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.StudentId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.StudentId }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.StudentId })
        </td>*@
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get `skills`  by `string.Join(",", stud.StudentSkills.Select(a => a.Skill.SkillName).ToList()` and use distinct to remove duplicated records

```cs
var students = (from stud in db.Students
                join con in db.Countries on stud.CountryId equals con.CountryId
                    join ct in db.Cities on stud.CityId equals ct.CityId
                    join rsm in db.Resumes on stud.ResumeID equals rsm.ResumeId
                    join stsk in db.StudentSkills on stud.StudentId equals stsk.StudentId

                //group stsk by stsk.StudentId into g
                //group stud by stud.StudentId into sg

                select new
                {
                    studentName = stud.StudentName,
                    countries = con.CountryName,
                    cities = ct.CityName,
                    skills = string.Join(",", stud.StudentSkills.Select(a => a.Skill.SkillName).ToList()),
                    resumes = rsm.ResumeName,
                    dateOfBirth = stud.DateOfBirth,
                }).Distinct().ToList();
```

and

```cs
foreach (var item in students)
{
    //var sk= sb.Append(item.skills + ",").ToString();
    studentLists.Add(new StudentListVM
    {
        studentName = item.studentName,
            countries = item.countries,
            cities = item.cities,
            //skills = string.Join(",", item.skills).ToString(),
            skills = item.skills.ToString(),
            resumes = item.resumes,
            dateOfBirth = item.dateOfBirth
    });
    //sb.Remove(sb.ToString().LastIndexOf(","), 1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry! I have specified already that, LINQ doesn't recognize StringJoin or StringBuilder! This doesn't work.